# Load arraylist of url using Glide

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap, android-glide

I'm trying to load ArrayList of URLs and get Bitmaps from them using glide my code below not working, Toast show me **0** as message.

```
   @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void getBitmapFromUrls() {
        final ArrayList<Bitmap> arrayBitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontTransform();
        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .apply(requestOptions)
                    .load(listItems.get(i).getImgUrl())
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            arrayBitmaps.add(resource);
                        }
                    });
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + arrayBitmaps.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call Glide to load images, it spawns some background threads to do jobs (loading images from a server). In the meantime you show a Toast on the UI thread to display size of the bitmap list. But at that time the background threads might be in processing and haven't returned result as well. So the size of bitmap list is 0.

You can change your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .asBitmap()
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .load(listItems.get(i).getImgUrl())
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    arrayBitmaps.add(resource);
                    // All images has been loaded and add to bitmap list as well.
                    if (arrayBitmaps.size == listItems.size()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + arrayBitmaps.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)